# Excel: Insert Copied Cells and pasting values only ... some of it

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros

I'm looking for an excel expert here and what I'm asking may not be possible.  Originally, I was looking for a macro to allow me to paste values after performing an insert copied cells and shifting down.  I finally asked ChatGPT the right question and was able to get it to spit out a successful macro that works, FYI:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    If Not Intersect(Target, Sh.Cells) Is Nothing Then
        If Application.CutCopyMode = xlCopy Then
            If Target.PasteSpecial(Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False) Then
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
            End If
        End If
    End If

    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

However, I'm now realizing I still need some of the cells to keep their formulas for pricing, for example.  I've attached a picture of a part, for example, below.  This is highlighted by the heading: Standard Wands.  I need to take the boxed outline and only paste the values from column A to E.  I need columns F to I to keep the paste to formulas, not values.

[Standard Wands](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G4y04.png)

The point is I want to take this data and paste it in another sheet where the description of the item will update based on the part# but the costing will stay a formula, see attached pictured with the headings: Item, Qty, Part#, Description, etc.

[Item, Qty, Part#, Description ...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0CUG.png)

Comment: Another way to go about it is to paste the standard formulas with a insert copied cells and shift down.  Then, automatically somehow repaste the data and replace columns A to E as paste special - values.  I couldn't get a macro to run successfully.

Comment: Why do you need to copy paste? if you have a unique part number, you can lookup the price or any other related information. Even if it's on another sheet